# Keeping data rows with same Unique ID after an Indicator variable changes from 1 to 0 for the first time in SAS

Tags: sas

I need help with a SAS code which would keep data rows with same Unique ID after meeting a certain condition. For example, if I have a dataset called BASE and is as shown below;

```
Account_Number  Default_Indicator
1010            0
1010            0
1010            1
1010            1
1010            1
1010            0
1010            0
1010            0
1010            1
1010            1
1020            0
1020            0
1020            0
1020            1
1020            1
1020            1
1020            0
1020            0
1020            1
1020            1
```

I would like the final dataset to keep rows after the Default_Indicator changes from 1 to 0 for the first time as shown below;

```
Account_Number  Default_Indicator
1010            0
1010            0
1010            0
1010            1
1010            1
1020            0
1020            0
1020            1
1020            1
```

Help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks I have removed the SQL tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use BY group processing, just add the NOTSORTED keyword to the BY statement.  Use the LAG() function to access the value from the previous data step iteration.  Retain the flag variable indicting that you have found a 1 -> 0 transition. Make sure to reset when starting a new account.

```
data have;
  row+1;
  input Account_Number Default_Indicator @@ ;
cards;
1010  0 1010  0
1010  1 1010  1 1010  1
1010  0 1010  0 1010  0
1010  1 1010  1
1020  0 1020  0 1020  0
1020  1 1020  1 1020  1
1020  0 1020  0
1020  1 1020  1
;

data want ;
  set have;
  by account_number default_indicator notsorted;
  lag_indicator=lag(default_indicator);
  if first.account_number then call missing(found,lag_indicator);
  if first.default_indicator and default_indicator=0 and lag_indicator=1 then found+1;
  if found then output;
  drop lag_indicator found;
run;
```

Results (without the DROP statement)

```
              Account_     Default_       lag_
Obs    row     Number     Indicator    indicator    found

 1       6      1010          0            1          1
 2       7      1010          0            0          1
 3       8      1010          0            0          1
 4       9      1010          1            0          1
 5      10      1010          1            1          1
 6      17      1020          0            1          1
 7      18      1020          0            0          1
 8      19      1020          1            0          1
 9      20      1020          1            1          1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, this code worked and I really appreciate your help!